# Makefile add last flag

Tags: makefile

I am trying to compile my project using makefile.

Command line that works perfectly for me is:

```
g++ -I stuff/ -L stuff2/ src/Core.cpp -o file_name -ljvm
```

If I miss `-ljvm` at the end I end up with an error while compiling, this flag must go after `file_name`. The problem is that I am unable to add `-ljvm` successfully using makefile.

My makefile looks like this:

```
NAME = 'AI'
SRC = src
TGT = obj
PRG = application
INCLUDES = -Iinclude -I /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include/
LIBRARIES = -L /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -O3 -std=c++0x $(INCLUDES) $(LIBRARIES)
SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.cpp)
OBJS = $(addprefix $(TGT)/, $(notdir $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)))

$(TGT)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(PRG)/$(NAME): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $@
```

Which gives me an error since I have not added `-ljvm`.

If I add it to: `$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -ljvm`, nothing changes and I still get same error.

If I add it to last line `$(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $@ -ljvm` I get a different error:

```
g++  obj/Core.o -o application/'AI' -ljvm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ljvm
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [application/'AI'] Error 1
```

I have a feeling that I am missing something simple here. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last line uses `$(LDFLAGS)` that is actually never defined.
`ld` complains about the fact it cannot find `-ljvm`, that's because you have to pass

```
-L /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/
```

to the linker (i.e. add it to your last command).
Try defining `LDFLAGS` with, at least, `$(LIBRARIES)` in it.

Comment: God dammit, I cant believe it worked. Thank you for your suggestion!